# I want to return data from duplicate rows SQL Query

Tags: oracle

I want to return data from duplicative rows

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1

COLUMN1   COLUMN2
-------   -------
CA         1
CB         2
CB         3
CC         4
CD         5
CE         6
CE         7
CE         8
CF         9
```

I want to return rows for 'CB' and CE. Here  CB and CE has more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I'd code this as follows:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 where column1 in ("CB", "CE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - this query first finds out those items in column1 who appear multiple time and then extract their information.

```
select * from table1
where column1 in (
    select column1 
    from table1 
    group by column1
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

If you are only interested in knowing the values in column1, you could just run:

```
select column1 
from table1 
group by column1
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try out this code. Basically the Query is in MySQL but you can use the same logic in Oracle Database. Here the inner subquery will find out the columns which is grouped by column1 and will return a column having a count greater than 1. The Outer query will display the rows of the column fetched by the inner query.Here I have created a table with the table name as **name**

SQL fiddle Added for your reference [SQLCODE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc41/3)

> select * from name where column1 in(select column1 from name
>   group by column1
>   having count(*)>1);